# C++ template: no compile error although an error is present

Tags: c++, templates, class-template, template-instantiation

can someone please shed some light on a curious phenomenon with C++ templates. Consider this simple code:

```
class B {};

template <typename T>
class A 
{
    T _v;
public:
    A() {}
    void add(T a) { _v += a; }
};

int main()
{
    A<B> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Clearly this isn't legal because the += operator is not defined for class B, and therefore the code inside the `add` method is invalid. Yet this code compiles fine!

It is not until you call the `add` method that you get a compile error:

```
int main()
{
    A<B> b;
    b.add(B()); // complains about a missing += operator
    return 0;
}
```

For a non-template class the compile error occurs regardless of whether the class is used at all.

```
class C
{
    B _v;
public:
    C() {}
    void add(B a) { _v += a; } // compile error here right away
};
```

Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Template members are not instanciated until ODR used. If you don't call the `add` function, it won't be instanciated, and no errors occur.

Comment: @Red.Wave  "instanciated" is not a word (in English, or in C++ nomenclature).   The word you are misspelling is instan*t*iated

Comment: @Peter Never been good at spelling. That's why I became CTRL+V guy

Answer (score 4):

If a member function of a class template is not used it is not instantiated.

In the second program the member functon of the class template `A` is used and the compiler tries to instantiate it. As a result it issues an error.

From the C++20 Standard (13.9.2 Implicit instantiation)

> 3 The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>
> (3.1) — **the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of
> the definitions, of the non-deleted class member functions**, member
> classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members, member
> templates, and friends; and
>
> (3.2) — the implicit instantiation of the definitions of deleted
> member functions, unscoped member enumerations, and member anonymous
> unions.

And there is an example

*[Example 3 :*

```
template<class T>
struct C {
    void f() { T x; }
    void g() = delete;
};
C<void> c; // OK, definition of C<void>::f is not instantiated at this point
template<> void C<int>::g() { } // error: redefinition of C<int>::g
```

*— end example]*

Such an approach allows to reduce the compilation time. You don't pay for what you don't use.